# issue with sed command

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am running into a strange issue. I want to extract the contents between two strings. The structure of the file is almost the same , but it differs in size.
The commands I am using are working well with one file `temp` but not with the other file `tmp2`.

```
-bash-3.2# cat temp
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management"><dp:timestamp>2015-01-22T13:38:04Z</dp:timestamp><dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i</dp:file><dp:file name="temporary://test1.txt">lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i</dp:file></dp:response></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Below commands are producing expected output

```
-bash-3.2# sed -n 's_<env:Envelope\(.*\)<dp:file name="temporary://test.txt">\([^>]*\)</dp:file>\(.*\)_\2_p' temp

XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i

-bash-3.2# sed -n 's_<env:Envelope\(.*\)<dp:file name="temporary://test1.txt">\([^>]*\)</dp:file>\(.*\)_\2_p' temp

lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i

-bash-3.2# cat tmp2
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><dp:response xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management"><dp:timestamp>2015-01-
27T11:10:38Z</dp:timestamp><dp:file name="temporary://BackUpDir/backupmanifest.xml">PFNlY3VyZUJhY2t1cE1hbmlmZXN0Pg0KPGJhY2t1cG1hbmlmZXN0Pg0KIDx2ZXJzaW9uPlhJNTAuNi4wLjAu
MTwvdmVyc2lvbj4NCiA8dGltZXpvbmU+R01UMEJTVDwvdGltZXpvbmU+DQogPGNvbmZpZz5hdXRvY29uZmlnLmNmZzwvY29uZmlnPg0KIDx0aW1lPjIwMTUtMDEtMjdUMTE6MDI6NTZaPC90aW1lPg0KIDxidWlsZD4yMzI3
Nzc8L2J1aWxkPg0KIDxidWlsZGRhdGU+MjAxMy8wOC8wMSAxOTo0MzozNjwvYnVpbGRkYXRlPg0KIDxjb21tb25jcml0ZXJpYT5vZmY8L2NvbW1vbmNyaXRlcmlhPg0KIDxzZXJpYWxudW1iZXI+NjhBNTkyNjwvc2VyaWFs
bnVtYmVyPg0KIDxjcnlwdG9DZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZT5zZWN1cmVfYmFja3VwPEZpbGVOYW1lPmNlcnQ6Ly8vc2VjdXJlX2JhY2t1cC1zc2NlcnQucGVtPC9GaWxlTmFtZT48L2NyeXB0b0NlcnRpZmljYXRlPg0KIDxlcGhlbWVy
Ukhwc3Bxb0V0YlU0SDBtOVkNCkJzVHEwRFhiTUk4WGNMc1NiUGc5WktRdlBzY2Y5Q0sxRDhwdUJjODM0akNOaDJCQnhlWWdMTzhnUWg5NXVjNHENCjVtMTlWNnhNYVBPNnpZZkM5Tk1XQmR5MVhIWDhwc2txdTVJeGdnSm5N
SUlDWXdJQkFUQm5NR0l4Q3pBSkJnTlYNCkJBWVRBbFZUTVF3d0NnWURWUVFLRXdOSlFrMHhKekFsQmdOVkJBc1RIbGRsWWxOd2FHVnlaU0JFWVhSaFVHOTMNClpYSWdRWEJ3YkdsaGJtTmxjekVjTUJvR0ExVUVBeE1UUTNW
emRHOXRaWElnVW1Wc1pXRnpaU0JEUVFJQkZqQUgNCkJnVXJEZ01DR3FDQjJEQVlCZ2txaGtpRzl3MEJDUU14Q3dZSktvWklodmNOQVFjQk1Cd0dDU3FHU0liM0RRRUoNCkJURVBGdzB4TlRBeE1qY3hNVEF5TlRaYU1DTUdD
U3FHU0liM0RRRUpCREVXQkJRbDc1cUJ3MWlWRHhkN0NjY1gNCjZ0UlNoVUJLblRCNUJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkNROHhiREJxTUFzR0NXQ0dTQUZsQXdRQktqQUxCZ2xnaGtnQlpRTUUNCkFSWXdDd1lKWUlaSUFXVURCQUVDTUFv
R0NDcUdTSWIzRFFNSE1BNEdDQ3FHU0liM0RRTUNBZ0lBZ0RBTkJnZ3ENCmhraUc5dzBEQWdJQlFEQUhCZ1VyRGdNQ0J6QU5CZ2dxaGtpRzl3MERBZ0lCS0RBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUYNCkFBU0NBUUF0NldRM2lzeExU
WFA4S2FyaThhOVZQUlVIeFgza3U4ZHNvOVk3dVBjMmdaZHZNWHZJWEhXL3RhR0oNCk8wdjBRdm54OHpOdU5NTnpOMjdUalVhN1E2NUt5OXJrVllJRHY4aGdOM2NwemhLZmI2N0plQ0s5S1NjMVllQTMNCmY3TTdhUXcrV0ps
WlpSTXVlZ2ZDK1BpMFNxZ1dXUTNVY1BIQlZvMFAzUDBRcXd2Mk1lQWJUZ1ROa1FMWm9pcU8NCkR4cVEvTjNaMzZrN25ORW85MUMvdks0SytmaklRWXplU09YbThJemd0NjlKd1BvYlhoUFhHZjBCRDNzUVVwTUENCm9QZ3E1
WExXM2lzMi9pamd4RVA1a1ZQR2E5dFNPd1dEYkJ1RzBNTDNkVkhsQ2lidndBSkdyTVlWR3l2Q2o4UHANCmx1WmpFdWk3cEhkV2laSGZWSGlXajdHY3Z3SVUNCjwvc2lnbmF0dXJlPg0KPC9TZWN1cmVCYWNrdXBNYW5pZmVz
dD4NCg==</dp:file><dp:file name="temporary://BackUpDir/cert.tgz">p6605/jI2ntpNM2jt0L0el8aq/fo+9OD2NsmfEF+P+whGQ/V1Bv94ph4FLcSm520piXl9krMYlwYnnWQl9uDNi25EIENdLHUHsnQFyJ
ykYN4k2YwpZJRIp8M6cYQX1fEzfdW2rpZrvprgT85ncSrVZC66oTxE37qZxqPyJJAHfOTld0hYt2</dp:file></dp:response></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

while below command is not producing any output. I am expecting it to print the content between `temporary://BackUpDir/backupmanifest.xml">` and first appearance of `</dp:file>`

```
sed -n 's_<env:Envelope\(.*\)<dp:file name="temporary://BackUpDir/backupmanifest.xml">\([^>]*\)</dp:file>\(.*\)_\2_p' tmp2
```

Where am I committing the mistake? Sorry for pasting the huge contents of the file, but I cant see an option to attach a file over here.

Comment: Are there newlines in tmp2?

Comment: Interestingly, this works for me (on sed 4.2.2 on Ubuntu), having cut and paste the `tmp2` XML and made sure I'd removed any newlines (`wc -l tmp2` outputs 1)...

Comment: this work after (copy/paste of your sample) i remove the insidious newline after `"><dp:timestamp>2015-01-` in first line of the sample

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to use a [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) parser. I can give you an example with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet). Use `-N` to add your namespace and `-v` to add the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression, like:

```
xmlstarlet sel \
  -N 'dp=http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management' \
  -t \
  -v '//dp:file/text()' \
temp
```

That yields:

```
XJzLXJlc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i
lc3VsdHMtYWN0aW9uX18i
```

And the same with the second one:

```
xmlstarlet sel \
  -N 'dp=http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management' \
  -t \
  -v '//dp:file/text()' \
temp2
```

That yields:

```
PFNlY3VyZUJhY2t1cE1hbmlmZXN0Pg0KPGJhY2t1cG1hbmlmZXN0Pg0KIDx2ZXJzaW9uPlhJNTAuNi4wLjAu
MTwvdmVyc2lvbj4NCiA8dGltZXpvbmU+R01UMEJTVDwvdGltZXpvbmU+DQogPGNvbmZpZz5hdXRvY29uZmlnLmNmZzwvY29uZmlnPg0KIDx0aW1lPjIwMTUtMDEtMjdUMTE6MDI6NTZaPC90aW1lPg0KIDxidWlsZD4yMzI3
Nzc8L2J1aWxkPg0KIDxidWlsZGRhdGU+MjAxMy8wOC8wMSAxOTo0MzozNjwvYnVpbGRkYXRlPg0KIDxjb21tb25jcml0ZXJpYT5vZmY8L2NvbW1vbmNyaXRlcmlhPg0KIDxzZXJpYWxudW1iZXI+NjhBNTkyNjwvc2VyaWFs
bnVtYmVyPg0KIDxjcnlwdG9DZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZT5zZWN1cmVfYmFja3VwPEZpbGVOYW1lPmNlcnQ6Ly8vc2VjdXJlX2JhY2t1cC1zc2NlcnQucGVtPC9GaWxlTmFtZT48L2NyeXB0b0NlcnRpZmljYXRlPg0KIDxlcGhlbWVy
Ukhwc3Bxb0V0YlU0SDBtOVkNCkJzVHEwRFhiTUk4WGNMc1NiUGc5WktRdlBzY2Y5Q0sxRDhwdUJjODM0akNOaDJCQnhlWWdMTzhnUWg5NXVjNHENCjVtMTlWNnhNYVBPNnpZZkM5Tk1XQmR5MVhIWDhwc2txdTVJeGdnSm5N
SUlDWXdJQkFUQm5NR0l4Q3pBSkJnTlYNCkJBWVRBbFZUTVF3d0NnWURWUVFLRXdOSlFrMHhKekFsQmdOVkJBc1RIbGRsWWxOd2FHVnlaU0JFWVhSaFVHOTMNClpYSWdRWEJ3YkdsaGJtTmxjekVjTUJvR0ExVUVBeE1UUTNW
emRHOXRaWElnVW1Wc1pXRnpaU0JEUVFJQkZqQUgNCkJnVXJEZ01DR3FDQjJEQVlCZ2txaGtpRzl3MEJDUU14Q3dZSktvWklodmNOQVFjQk1Cd0dDU3FHU0liM0RRRUoNCkJURVBGdzB4TlRBeE1qY3hNVEF5TlRaYU1DTUdD
U3FHU0liM0RRRUpCREVXQkJRbDc1cUJ3MWlWRHhkN0NjY1gNCjZ0UlNoVUJLblRCNUJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkNROHhiREJxTUFzR0NXQ0dTQUZsQXdRQktqQUxCZ2xnaGtnQlpRTUUNCkFSWXdDd1lKWUlaSUFXVURCQUVDTUFv
R0NDcUdTSWIzRFFNSE1BNEdDQ3FHU0liM0RRTUNBZ0lBZ0RBTkJnZ3ENCmhraUc5dzBEQWdJQlFEQUhCZ1VyRGdNQ0J6QU5CZ2dxaGtpRzl3MERBZ0lCS0RBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUYNCkFBU0NBUUF0NldRM2lzeExU
WFA4S2FyaThhOVZQUlVIeFgza3U4ZHNvOVk3dVBjMmdaZHZNWHZJWEhXL3RhR0oNCk8wdjBRdm54OHpOdU5NTnpOMjdUalVhN1E2NUt5OXJrVllJRHY4aGdOM2NwemhLZmI2N0plQ0s5S1NjMVllQTMNCmY3TTdhUXcrV0ps
WlpSTXVlZ2ZDK1BpMFNxZ1dXUTNVY1BIQlZvMFAzUDBRcXd2Mk1lQWJUZ1ROa1FMWm9pcU8NCkR4cVEvTjNaMzZrN25ORW85MUMvdks0SytmaklRWXplU09YbThJemd0NjlKd1BvYlhoUFhHZjBCRDNzUVVwTUENCm9QZ3E1
WExXM2lzMi9pamd4RVA1a1ZQR2E5dFNPd1dEYkJ1RzBNTDNkVkhsQ2lidndBSkdyTVlWR3l2Q2o4UHANCmx1WmpFdWk3cEhkV2laSGZWSGlXajdHY3Z3SVUNCjwvc2lnbmF0dXJlPg0KPC9TZWN1cmVCYWNrdXBNYW5pZmVz
dD4NCg==
p6605/jI2ntpNM2jt0L0el8aq/fo+9OD2NsmfEF+P+whGQ/V1Bv94ph4FLcSm520piXl9krMYlwYnnWQl9uDNi25EIENdLHUHsnQFyJ
ykYN4k2YwpZJRIp8
```

Comment: I cant find the entry for this command on the solaris machine which we are using.

Comment: Upvoted for what seems to be a really useful tool (albeit not on the OP's box) I didn't know about, but have wanted...

Comment: @user2607367: Neither did I, you will need to install it from your package manager, source code or whatever you know how.

Comment: It seems to be a really useful tool, but somehow, I don't have privilege on this machine to install packages and I might need to go through a lengthy process to get it installed.If you can help me in understanding where did I go wrong with the 'sed' command that I had used, it will be more helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment (and another), there doesn't seem anything wrong with your sed commands (though yes, probably not the most maintainable / readable solution long-term), it seems to be a newline issue.

So to verify it's all on one line:

```
wc -l tmp2
```

should produce `1`... and to make sure anyway:

```
tr -d '\n' tmp2 | sed -n ...
```

Comment: I tried this:
`cat tmp2|tr -d '\n'`  the `wc -l tmp2` outputs to 0.